# AAPT: error: attribute android:Layout_margin not found

Tags: android, kotlin, runtime-error, margin

I have this peoblem when I run the app. I could not solve it. I need to run this app but I stop with this issue
`

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:Layout_margin="10pt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buaccept"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="buAcceptEvent"
            android:text="@string/accept" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/burequest"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="buRequestEvent"
            android:text="@string/request" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etEmail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/other_player_email"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

`

I tried to Put Top Bottom Right Left to margin but the same error